# Looking for a good ePub3 boilerplate/IDE

Tags: html, ide, epub, developer-tools, epub3

As web-developer I'm struggling finding a good base to create my own ePub3 eBook: I found tons of tutorials about how to use ebook related softwares (InDesign, Calibre etc), but none about how to create by my own a standard fitting ePub3 project (best for now  is https://www.edrlab.org/epub/).

Now my question is: where I can find a good resource on rules, standards,  best practices, tools and tests about ePub3? And maybe some good examples too...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are some places I've found that have good information:

ePub3 Overview

http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-overview.html

MobileRead Wiki

https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/EPUB3

MobileRead ePub Forum

https://www.mobileread.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=179

ePub Secrets

http://epubsecrets.com/